# Flask only returning one value

Tags: python, flask

I have a function that pulls info from the web and I can print it to my console without a problem. However, I'm running into issues with having the flask application print the info to the browser. Here's what I have so far:

```
from craigslist import CraigslistForSale
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_info():
    item = CraigslistForSale(site='southjersey', 
        category='fua', filters={'max_price':200})
    for product in item.get_results():
        a = product
        return a['name'], a['price']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

From the code above, my browser only shows one name of one return value. for example, only `a['name']` of the first return value, no price and no other objects.

Why is this happening (only displaying one single value), and how can I work around this to display the entire return object (which is a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
from craigslist import CraigslistForSale
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_info():
    item = CraigslistForSale(site='southjersey', 
        category='fua', filters={'max_price':200})

    return render_template('index.html', items=item.get_results())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Template (`index.html`):

```
{% for product in items %}
    {{ product['name'] }}
    {{ product['price'] }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```